# Prove that $G$ contains subgroups $H_i$ such that $\dots \subset H_{-2} \subset H_{-1} \subset H_0 \subset H_1\subset H_2 \subset \dots$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be the group generated by the matrices
>   $$x= \begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \ \ \ y=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$
>   where the group operation is matrix multiplication. Prove that $G$ contains a subgroup $H_i$ for each $i\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
>   $$\dots \subset H_{-2} \subset H_{-1} \subset H_0 \subset H_1\subset H_2 \subset \dots $$

Here is what I got so far:
$$x^my^n=\begin{pmatrix}2^m & n2^m \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},\ \ \ y^nx^m=\begin{pmatrix}2^m & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
but I have no idea how useful they are.

I think it is easy to make infinite amount of subsets in one side, eg $\dots \subset \langle x^8 \rangle \subset \langle x^4 \rangle\subset \langle x^2 \rangle\subset \langle x \rangle$. But no idea how to make infinite amount of subsets on both sides.

Comment: Hint: (1) describe $G$ as by an implicit formula (rather than a parameterization) (2) try not to define these subgroups in terms of group elements in $\langle x,y\rangle$, but as set of matrices.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly the have in mind, but one such collection of subgroups is 
$$
H_i = \left \langle \pmatrix{1&2^i\\0&1} \right \rangle = \langle x^{i}y x^{-i} \rangle
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks. I believe you mean $$H_i= \left \langle \pmatrix{1&2^{-i}\\0&1} \right \rangle = \langle x^{-i}y x^{i} \rangle$$ So, we could have $H_i \subset H_{i+1}$. May I know briefly how you get to these subgroups? I was guessing $H_i$ is generated by an element which is some combination of $x,y$, but (beside trial and error) I have no idea how to get the "some combination".

Comment: I don't think I followed any straight path there.  I think it is was helpful to know, however, that the group
$$
\left\{
S = \pmatrix{a&b\\0&1}:a,b \in \Bbb R
\right\}
$$
can be identified with the [affine group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group) of transformations over $\Bbb R^1$.  I suspected that the $G$ given was topologically dense in $S$, which perhaps gave me a better sense of what kinds of elements I had to work with.  Notably, we would identify $\pmatrix{1&b\\0&1}$ with a translation $b$ units in the positive direction.